# Why does a regex with `(something)?` quantifier followed `.*` seems to match everything to the `.*`?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

Given this text:

```
25% on $53,501 to $78,100.
```

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/6g52XL/1) captures the 3 numbers into the three capturing groups (as expected)

```
^(\d+\.?\d+).*?(\d+,?\d+).*?(\d+,\d+)?.$
```

However, I would expect this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/6g52XL/3) to match all 3 groups as well, but the 3rd group is empty.

```
^(\d+\.?\d+).*?(\d+,?\d+).*?(\d+,\d+)?.*$
```

The only difference between the first and second regex is that while the first one ends with `.$`, the second one ends with `.*$`.

Granted that the second regex can be satisfied without matching anything to the third group, but I would expect the `?` in `(\d+,\d+)?` to match the pattern zero or one times, but one time preferably as it is greedy. In that case the last `.*` matches nothing, and the whole regex should still be satisfied.

So, why does the regex engine "skip over" the third group and prefer to match the rest of the string with the `.*`?

Comment: consider the second `.*?`

Comment: do you know about "regex debugger" on regex101 site? see tools menu

Comment: Because the last group is optional, when it fails on the first character after `$53,501`, the following `.*` absorbs all the characters up to end of string. You can see if you put that in a capture group i.e. `^(\d+\.?\d+).*?(\d+,?\d+).*?(\d+,\d+)?(.*)$`, it captures `_to N $78,100.` (where `_` represents the space after `$53,501`

Comment: If you can't make the third group non-optional, you might want to consider using `\D` or `[^\d]` instead of `.` e.g. https://regex101.com/r/SMILQA/1

Comment: @jhnc the purpose of the `.` is to match the last character in the string; in this case it happens to be a literal dot/period. The only difference in the two regexes is that the second one has the zero-or-more qualifier applied to the dot at the end.

Comment: Just checking, since the final character happens to be a literal period and `.` matches more than that

Comment: @Nick - Regarding your first comment, wouldn't same logic apply to the first regex too, but that one captures all 3 numbers. The `.*?` between the capture groups is lazy so that it captures as little as possible until it encounters the next number; but it does not capture anything either with the second regex (as the last `.*` captures everything, like you pointed out). In the first regex though the `.*?` between the two dollar amounts does capture ` to N $`, which is another difference between the two regexes.

Comment: @sudocracy no, because the `.` after the third capture group can't match all the characters from the current point to end of string. So the regex engine is forced to keep going, and eventually runs into digits which match the third capture gorup

Comment: Because you made both sequential patterns optional. It is not how an optional group is added. It should be all wrapped with an optional non-capturing group, and the capturing group must be obligatory (see [fix](https://regex101.com/r/6g52XL/4)). Link is provided at the top of the question.

Comment: I also added a link to my old answer where I explain exactly this issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - If I am following you other answer, in my case, when the engine encounters the second lazy pattern (`.*?`) that I intended to capture `_to_` (underscore represents space) into, it is going to skip making an attempt, and so tries to match the `\d` with the `_` and so skips that group as well, and find the `.*` that can capture the entire string. Correct? 
Feel free to add an answer, and I can accept it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - The flaw in my thinking was to think that `.*?` will match as little as possible until the next digit. But really, I should have considered this regex can be satisfied even when the lazy pattern matches nothing in *spite of the fact that last `(\d+,\d+)?` is greedy* (and the engine will attempt a match for that part).